# javascript execute function with time interval

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the simple function of changing content of container div.
There is a `<table>` inside the container `<div>`, with 2 `<td>`s, the javascript simply moves left this `<table>` and it works, but `onclick` and I need to execute the moving function with time interval.

```
 <div onclick="move(this.children[0])" class="table_wrap">
 <div class="table_scroll" style="left: 0px;">

 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" width="1920px">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: red;">
            a
        </td>
        <td style="background-color: blue;">
            b
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>

 </div>
 </div>

   <script language="javascript">
 function move(elem) {

          var left = 0

          function frame() {

            left -= 5;  // update parameters 

            elem.style.left = left + 'px' // show frame 

            if (left == -965)  // check finish condition
              clearInterval(id)
          }
          var id = setInterval(frame, 1) // draw every 10ms
        }

       </script>
```

And CSS:

```
 <style type="text/css">
 .table_wrap{
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 width: 967px;
 height: 250px;
 left: -2px;
 top: 5px;
 }
 .table_wrap .table_scroll{
 position: absolute;
 text-align:center;
 white-space:nowrap;
 }
 </style>
```

I tryed to use `setInterval`, but failed.

http://jsfiddle.net/hqztm2dt/1/ here is the JSfiddle, just click on the red line..
Thanks in advance for the attention !

Comment: `id` is a local variable, and will be destroyed as soon as the execution of `frame` has ended. You've to declare the said variable outside of `frame`. Also you'd probably need a `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: If it works but not as expexted, perhaps your interval is too fast? setInterval takes in ms...so 1 = 1 ms regardless 10 ms is still really fast!

Comment: the function works fine, the problem is that it's been executed by clicking on the div.. And I need it to be executed with time interval..

Comment: Could you please include an example of where you try with `setInterval` (or preferably `setTimeout`)?

Comment: It's pretty difficult to diagnose what you did wrong with your `setInterval` if you don't show us what you did.  My gut feeling is that because you don't have an `id` on the `<div>` your code is no longer able to (easily) access it through the DOM

Comment: Thanks for the attention.. The answer of @Naeem Shaikh is what I needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you need to move it on interval,  see this: 
>   http://jsfiddle.net/gsddsxgy/2/ (here the time interval is 3ms)

**html:**

```
<div  class="table_wrap">
 <div id='move' class="table_scroll" style="left: 0px;">

 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" width="1920px">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: red;">
            a
        </td>
        <td style="background-color: blue;">
            b
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>

 </div>
 </div>
```

**JS:**

```
setInterval(function(){ 

var elem=document.getElementById('move');
 var left = 0

          function frame() {

            left -= 5;  // update parameters 

            elem.style.left = left + 'px' // show frame 

            if (left == -965)  // check finish condition
              clearInterval(id)
          }
          var id = setInterval(frame, 1) // draw every 10ms






    }, 3000);
```

> If you need to move the div on click but after a little time gap, see
>   this http://jsfiddle.net/gsddsxgy/

**code:**

```
function move(elem) {
setTimeout(function(){ 


 var left = 0

          function frame() {

            left -= 5;  // update parameters 

            elem.style.left = left + 'px' // show frame 

            if (left == -965)  // check finish condition
              clearInterval(id)
          }
          var id = setInterval(frame, 1) // draw every 10ms



}, 1000);

        }
```

Comment: @JaniBolkvadze:- glad, but can you share which one of the above solution helped you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gsddsxgy/2/ that's what I needed.. thank you for the attention..

Comment: Once more question please: moving stops when (left == -965).. Then code executes moving again.. Should I use javascript Loop to stop it? I need it to be executed once.

Comment: simply using setTimeout? that's it, thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code in jsFiddle is the move function isn't defined when trying to call it - if you use addEventListener you can bind the method to the click event using just javascript and not the onClick attribute. Using your code:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('wrapper');
elem.addEventListener('click', move);

function move() {

    var left = 0

    function frame() {

        left -= 5;  // update parameters 

        elem.style.left = left + 'px' // show frame 

        if (left == -965)  // check finish condition
            clearInterval(id)
        }

    var id = setInterval(frame, 1) // draw every 10ms
}
```

JS fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/b1q7poj4/2/